# connection and fundamental group of real and complex quadrics

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, connectedness, fundamental-groups, quadrics

I would like to calculate the fundamental group of real and complex quadrics. I've seen it in the projective space, but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$. Also, I would like to prove that they are connected (or at least I think they are?), but I can't think about anything...

Comment: In $\Bbb C^n$, I believe you can use induction with the "branched covering trick" : a conic in $\Bbb C^2$ is a cylinder and for higher dimension you should be able to express it as a ramified covering of $\Bbb C^{n-1}$ along another quadric. For real I don't know, but it probably depends on the quadric, as for example for $n=3$ in $\Bbb RP^3$ there are already two kind of smooth quadric (torus and spheres).

Comment: In fact, I believe it depends on the quadric : taking again the example of $\Bbb C^2$, a conic can be isomorphic to $\Bbb C^*$ or $\Bbb C$ which have different fundamental groups, so I am not sure what kind you expect in the general case ...

Comment: @N.H. Yeah, maybe the general case would be too long and complex to treat, but I would like to see some particular cases. For instance, you can always take canonical forms, and then go from there. I would like to see how to conclude some of them are spheres and some are tori (except for sphere, of course!). As far as connection is concerned, I think that it shoud be easy to show they are path connected, so...

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ they are connected. But not necessarily over $\mathbb{R}$ : think about the two-sheeted hyperboloid.

Comment: @Roland yeah, but that is obvious (I should have been more clear though). I was talking about apparently connected conics, such as cilinder or one of the two sheet of the hyperboloid... For instance, I think the $\pi_1$ of the cilinder is $\mathbb{Z}$, because you retract everything to a sphere without two points and then do a stereographic projection.

Comment: A sheet of your hyperboloid I think is simply connected. Because you consider the space, you take out a line paraallel to the axis of the paraboloid minus the point of intersection, then I think you can retract on the hyperboloid. The space obtained by removing a line without a point can be deformed into a sphere without the points at the poles and a $D^2$ intersecting it. By using van Kampen and stereographic projection again you have simple connection. A more difficult case is when you have an hyperbolic paraboloid, I would like to see how to compute its $\pi_1$

Comment: Oh ok, indeed the phrase "I would like to prove that they are connected" was not really clear... About your problem, I would start computing their homology/cohomology which is not very hard, but you will have to consider the different quadrics at infinity. If this quadric is smooth, then over $\mathbb{C}$, they are all simply connected, except in dimension 1 (where you get $\mathbb{C}^*$). Over $\mathbb{R}$ and in dimension 2, the sheets of a two sheeted hyperboloid as well as the paraboloid are obviously contractible since they are homeomorphic to a plane.

Comment: @Roland I believe what you say is true, but as far as algebraic topology is concerned, I have only seen the fundamental group, coverings and monodromy, so I have no idea what homology and cohomology groups are